# Using /usr/bin/time and redirecting the output into a file?

Tags: time

So I'm using /usr/bin/time to measure my program, and I'm doing multiple runs of the same program so I can gather results. The problem with doing multiple executions and using /usr/bin/time at the same time is that it'll print out that giant chunk of information multiple times, and I don't want to scroll, copy, and paste my results into a text file. I'd rather have the command line do it for me.

Originally, I thought the command was something like:

```
/usr/bin/time -v sudo ./programname >> timeoutput.txt
```

But as far as I know, >> is used for stdout, so it won't work in this case.

Comment: The question is not completly clear to me, what type of output does your program use, files or stdout? In case it uses a file, you can add the content of that file by using `cat file >> timeoutput.txt`

Comment: `>` writes to file and `>>` appends to file.

Comment: It mostly uses stdout. I thought that didn't matter? I just wanted to take the output from /usr/bin/time and put it in a file, rather than print it out to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to append the standard *error* of `time` (which is the handle it uses for outputting the time information) to a file, you can use:

```
( time sleep 1 ) 2>>timeoutput.txt
```

The `2>>...` bit redirects standard *error* rather than standard output and the `()` ensures that the redirection applies to `time` rather than the command you're running.

Of course, that won't stop any error output from the program you're timing from showing up in the file, if you want to guarantee that, you need something like:

```
( time ( sleep 1 2>/dev/null ) ) 2>>timeoutput.txt
```

This will ensure that no error output from the command trickles out to interfere with the error output of `time`.

In the above examples, I've used `sleep 1` for the command but you should just replace that with whatever command you're trying to run.

Comment: What's the difference between /usr/bin/time and time? I guess my main concern is that will the results of using one compared to the other be the same, both quantity-wise and what both of them measure/print out?

Comment: There's no difference provided `/usr/bin` is in your path before any other directory containing a `time` executable. Use the full pathname if you want to ensure a specific one is chosen but it's usually not necessary. You can tell by executing `whence time` or `which time` to see where it finds it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, time and /usr/bin/time may well be different.  Some shells have a built in time function, note as follows from my ksh on Red Hat:

/usr/bin/time date
Thu Oct 31 12:57:04 EDT 2013
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2864maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+227minor)pagefaults 0swaps

time date
Thu Oct 31 12:57:11 EDT 2013

real    0m0.00s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s